# ¿Como hago para ir autocompletando la escritura en flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
SubTitleForm(title: 'Dirección', size: 18),
            BotomForm(
              textController: direccCtr,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            ),
            SubTitleForm(title: 'Ciudad', size: 18),
            BotomForm(
                textController: ciudadCtr,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.text),
            SubTitleForm(title: 'Correo', size: 18),
            BotomForm(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              textController: emailCtr,
            ),
            SubTitleForm(title: 'Celular', size: 18),
            BotomForm(
              textController: celCtr,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            ),
            SubTitleForm(title: 'Telefono', size: 18),
            BotomForm(
```

Tengo un formulario para solicitar datos y uno de ellos es **ciudades**.

¿Cómo hago para que cuando esté escribiendo el nombre de la ciudad, me vayan apareciendo las ciudades cuyos nombres tiene caracteres similares?

Tengo el listado de ciudades en la carpeta `model, ciudades.dart`

Pongo imagen de ejemplo de como deseo implementarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar el package `flutter_typeahead`, es muy útil para estos casos, funciona como un `TextField` en el cual escribes algo y te filtra en base a lo que escribes.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_typeahead

Ejemplo de uso:

```dart
import 'package:flutter_typeahead/flutter_typeahead.dart';
```

```dart
TypeAheadField(
  textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
    autofocus: true,
    style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style.copyWith(
      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic
    ),
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      border: OutlineInputBorder()
    )
  ),
  suggestionsCallback: (pattern) async {
    // aquí llamas a tu servicio pasándole el filtro "pattern" que es lo que el usuario escribió.
    return await BackendService.getSuggestions(pattern);
  },
  itemBuilder: (context, suggestion) {
    // aquí usas cualquier widget que quieras mostrar como elemento de resultado.
    return ListTile(
      leading: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
      title: Text(suggestion['name']),
      subtitle: Text('\$${suggestion['price']}'),
    );
  },
  onSuggestionSelected: (suggestion) {
    // una vez que seleccionas el elemento, puedes realizar cualquier acción, aquí están llamando a otra página.
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => ProductPage(product: suggestion)
    ));
  },
)
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]